# How to implement an autosave function in Python and PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, autosave

I have a current software which has a save function implemented using a FileSaveDialog to allow the user to save their project. However I want to implement an autosave feature that will do this save every so often to save a file with the current date and time in case the program crashes so there is always a record of the project.

Here's the code for the saveProject function. Any help on adding an auto-save feature would be much appreciated.

```
def saveProject(self):

    """Save the project (current assembly) in a .ccad file"""

    self.l.debug("Saving project")

    # Let user choose saving file
    dst = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
        self, "Save project", "", "CCAD files (*.ccad *.CCAD)"
    )

    if not dst[0]:
        self.l.debug("No destination file, exiting saveProject")
        return

    self.l.debug(f"Saving project to {dst}")

    # Save main attributes of assembly
    try:
        self.ass.saveProject(dst[0])
    except Exception as e:
        self.l.error(f"Couldn't save project: {e}", exc_info=True)
```

Comment: Why can you not just call the code when a certain time elapses? Use a thread so it doesn't interfere with your code and use time.sleep to wait for certain amount of time then call the saveProject

Comment: Or just use a `QTimer` and connect the `QTimer.timeout` signal to `saveProject`.

Comment: Hi both, 

Thank you for your responses. How would I connect the QTimer signal to saveProject in order to autosave? And how how I autosave with a particular filename - say including the current date and time rather than having the dialog box appear each time it needs to save?

Comment: Using `except Exception` like this is bad practice, be careful!

Comment: What would you suggest instead of using except Exception in this case? Thanks!